# Oracle APEX: how to select a default value of a radio group

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a radio group based on LOV with two options. I want to make first option selected by default.

I tied setting the default value to a static value but that did not work and radio group still comes up with nothing selected on page load. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the default is the correct way.  Most likely you have defaulted the **display** value you want?  It needs to be the **return** value (e.g. DEPTNO not DNAME).

Comment: I did set the return value

Comment: In that case I don't know why it isn't working for you.  There must be something wrong somewhere.

Comment: My return value is a string. Could that be an issue?

Comment: No, as long as what you type in the default is exactly the same as one of the return values of the LOV it should work.

Comment: Strange thing - I inspected the page html and that option in my radio group shows up as `checked`. But on the page nothing shows up as selected:((

Comment: found the issue - I was clearing the radio group on page load. All I wanted was to reset it to a default value but instead it clears it completely